# Reasoning behind integrating f(x)/g(x)?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometric-integrals

I understand the method to integrate this function would be:

$\int{\frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1} \thinspace dx}$

Divide all terms by $x^2$:

$= \int{\frac{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{x^4}{x^2}-\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}} \thinspace dx}$

=$ \int{\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2-1+\frac{1}{x^2}} \thinspace dx}$

Factor the denominator:

=$ \int{\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{(x-\frac{1}{x})^2 + 1} \thinspace dx}$

Use $u$-substitution:

$ u = x -\frac{1}{x}, du = 1 +\frac{1}{x^2} \thinspace dx$

$ \int{\frac{du}{u^2+1}} $

$= \tan^{-1}{(x-\frac{1}{x})}+C$

I can verify that this is the correct method using the chain rule:

$u = x-\frac{1}{x}, \frac{du}{dx} = 1 +\frac{1}{x^2} $

$y = \tan^{-1}{u}, \frac{dy}{du} = \frac{1}{u^2+1} $

$ \frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{1}{u^2+1} \times (1 +\frac{1}{x^2})$

$=  \frac{1 +\frac{1}{x^2}}{u^2+1} $

$ =  \frac{1 +\frac{1}{x^2}}{u^2+1} $

$ =  \frac{\frac{x^2 +1}{x^2}}{(x-\frac{1}{x})^2+1} $

$ =  \frac{\frac{x^2 +1}{x^2}}{x^2-2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1} $

$ =  \frac{\frac{x^2 +1}{x^2}}{\frac{x^4-x^2+1}{x^2}} $

$ =  \frac{x^2 +1}{x^4-x^2+1} $

Only after differentiating the resulting integral, does it make sense where the $x^2$ comes from.
As some terms are fractions, distributing the denominator and dividing all terms by the same common denominator simplifies the function.

$$  \frac{\frac{x^2 +1}{x^2}}{\frac{x^4-x^2+1}{x^2}} =  \frac{x^2 +1}{x^4-x^2+1} $$

So it makes sense then that this is the term we will multiply with the original integral in order to make it more useful to work with.

Firstly, is there a name for this technique, that is, multiply all terms by some function of x in order to make it easier to factor into something integratable?

Is there a telltale way to recognise when to use this method, and what the divisor should be (obviously without knowing the answer and working backwards)?

Are there any other ways to solve this integral?

Sometimes I don't feel this method is *intuitive* enough to remember in exam conditions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way to do it. I would go for this way if I don't immediately see a trick.

It's a big theorem that all rational functions have elementary antiderivatives. The general way to integrate a rational function is to factor it into quadratics and linears (this is always possible by FTA), and use partial fractions decomposition.

For our specific example, we have to factor $x^4-x^2+1$. The following is a somewhat common trick:

$$x^4-x^2+1 = x^4+2x^2+1 - 3x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt3x)^2 = (x^2-\sqrt3x+1)(x^2+\sqrt3x+1)$$

For the partial fraction decomposition, it seems reasonable that the numerators should be constants; fortunately, we can even guess them

$$\dfrac {x^2+1}{(x^2-\sqrt3x+1)(x^2+\sqrt3x+1)}= \dfrac {1/2}{x^2-\sqrt3x+1}+ \dfrac {1/2}{x^2+\sqrt3x+1}$$

And now the way you integrate $\frac {1}{ \text{quadratic}}$ is you complete the square on the bottom.

**Completing the Square:** From $x^2+bx+c$ we can complete the square to $\left(x+\dfrac {b}{2}\right)^2+ \left( c-\dfrac {b^2}{4} \right)$. This means that

$$\dfrac {1}{x^2+\sqrt3x+1} = \dfrac {1}{(x+\frac {\sqrt 3}{2})^2+\frac 14}$$

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the method I am after.

Comment: @jackw11111 You’re welcome!

Comment: Hi Ovi, i'm unsure how to factorize the denominators. I've tried completing the square and got up to x^2+2\sqrt{3}x+3-2-\sqrt{3}x.

Comment: @jackw11111 If edited the question with more steps. Please have a look and let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. But, just one last hang up, integrating the partial fractions after completing the square would give two inverse tan functions, and that is different to the first method...

Comment: @jackw11111 Integration problems are sort of famous for the fact that if you do them different ways, you get different looking results; but of course, in the end, the results end up equaling each other ($\pm$ a constant). It can be an exercise in itself, using trig identities and such, to show that two results are equal. But if you just want to convince yourself that both results are right, you don't have to go that far; you can just graph both reults, and their graphs should be the same, except for one of them possibly being shifted up/down.

Comment: Okay, that's cool. Yes, I saw the square root 3 and 2 out the front of the inverse tan and began imagining how the 30-60 triangle related to the graph of x-1/x, and if inverse tan had combinatory rules similar to natural log and got stuck, so I'll definitely be taking your word on it for now. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @jackw11111 You're welcome. If you have trouble showing the two answers are the same you can of course ask a question about that on this site.